# How to make batch operations in NDB is atomic or lock record for update ndb

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am beginner in google app engine and NDB. My problem: if i have 1 entity in model,
i want to prevent conflict when 2 parallel operations, code examples:

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model)
  count = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  def update_value(delta)
    count=count +delta
```

operation 1:

```
my_obj1= MyModel.get_by_id(1)
my_obj1.update_value(10)
my_obj1.put()
```

operation 2:

```
my_obj2= MyModel.get_by_id(1)
my_obj2.update_value(20)
my_obj2.put()
```

If 2 sessions call 2 operation in parallel, and before operations count=0 for entity(id=1). I want to prevent conflict on count value ,
 for example:

```
 operation1: read my_obj1 from entity(id=1) 
 operation2: read my_obj2 from entity(id=1)
 operation1: update_value(10) #count =10
 operation2: update_value(20) # count=20
 operation1: put() # save to ndb with count =10 
 operation2: put() # save to ndb with count=20
```

count=20 in ndb.
Desire value of count=30 in ndb.

Please show me the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use transactions for this. But it will not scale.

Comment: Thank you! I will try use transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [lock](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#lock-objects) object and hope this [blog](http://blog.notdot.net/2011/10/Migrating-to-Python-2-7-part-1-Threadsafe) may help.

Comment: I can use lock for class MyModel, thus, every entity of this class have to waiting for getting lock. The application's speed will be slow down. If we have no a completed solution, we can use data-fix solution for this scenario.